# Determine if Dictionary has entries that exist in List

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm guessing the answer to this will be simple but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I am trying to add entries from a `List` into a `Dictionary` (and in other situations I'm just checking to see if any of the `List` entries exist in the `Dictionary`.

```
private Dictionary<string, long> someDict;
public List<string> someList;

//someDict might have entries added here, someList is populated here

//Check if someDict currently has ANY entries from someList
if(someDict.ContainsKey(someList.RETURNALL)
{ 
    //may or may not add entries here depending on other conditions
    if(someOtherCondition){
       //Add any or all entries from someList into someDict using timestamp as second-column entry for someDict
    }
}
```

Obviously `RETURNALL` isn't an actual method, this is where I get stuck. I know I can use `Union` to join up `Lists` and am hoping there is something I can do here.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure LINQ solution:

```
if (someList.Any(someDict.ContainsKey)) {
  ...
}
```

This also has the advantage of using the dictionary's internal hash table efficiently, and will stop iterating the list as soon as one matching item is found.

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for! I was thinking of it backwards (the `List` being the parameter)

Comment: You could do `someDict.Keys.Any(someList.Contains)`, but that doesn't use the dictionary hashtable efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to check all of them? 
I think you must loop through each and find out, something like:

```
foreach(var i in someList)
{
if(someDict.ContainsKey(i)
{ 
    //may or may not add entries here depending on other conditions
    if(someOtherCondition){
       //Add any or all entries from someList into someDict using timestamp as second-column entry for someDict
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yeah I was hoping to avoid using any loops but that might be what i have to do. Was hoping there was a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, the loop is the light footprint here, it won't affect much, the check for existence is the one which would have taken time, but thanks to the Dictionary.ContainsKey which has complexity of about O(1)

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most efficient method, but obviously you can write your own function for this:

```
private bool ContainsAny(Dictionary<string, long> someDict, List<string> someList) {
 foreach(string listItem in someList) {
  if (someDict.containsKey(listItem)) {
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

This should simply check if the given dictionary contains any of the value in the given list.

Comment: As I am going to run these checks everywhere in my code I'll have to consider writing my own function. That's why I was asking my initial question; was hoping that there already existed a function built into the framework :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the value in someDict.

```
long tmp;
foreach(var i in someList)
{
  if(someDict.TryGetValue(i, out tmp))
  { 
    //may or may not add entries here depending on other conditions
    if(someOtherCondition(tmp)){
       //Add any or all entries from someList into someDict using timestamp as second-column entry for someDict
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      private Dictionary<string, long> someDict;
      public List<string> someList;

        foreach (string t in someList.Where(t => someDict.ContainsKey(t)))
        {
              if(someOtherCondition){ }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking nhouser9's idea, but generalized by using a templated [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsAny<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> someDict, IEnumerable<K> someList)
    {
        foreach(K listItem in someList)
        {
            if(someDict.ContainsKey(listItem))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can write

```
if(someDict.ContainsAny(someList))
```

or even

```
if(someDict.ContainsAny(new string[] {"a","b"}))
```